# When is the countable intersection of open sets a closed set?

Tags: general-topology

> When is the countable intersection of open sets a closed set? (I.e., what are sufficient conditions for the closedness of the intersection?)

Comment: Are you working in the real line?

Comment: Intersection of decreasing sequence of open sets need not be closed even if its closure is also decreasing: consider $O_n = (0,1+1/n)$.

Comment: I know, I'm looking for conditions for which the claim is correct , in the real line isn't true

Comment: Did you try $\overline{O_{n+1}}\subset O_n$?

Comment: But you stated you thought it was true if $\overline { O_{ n + 1 } } \subset \overline {O_n}.$ So what's going on when you say to @HanulJeon that "you know".

Comment: $O_n = (-\infty, -n] \cup [n, + \infty)$. Boundedness seems essential, and then it's just by compactness.

Comment: Of course, it you just want to know if it's *closed*, well, $\emptyset$ is closed ;)

Comment: What space are you in? Are you trying to show that a closed set is a $G_{\delta}$ set, that is, a countable intersection of open sets? This is true in some topological spaces, including  all metrizable spaces, but not in all topological spaces.